# Return a string list of all names from a list of objects

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of account objects:

```
Account {
  val id: String
  val description: String
  val firstName: String
  val lastName: String
}
```

I want to list all first names that exist in the Accounts list. How can I accomplish this? Is there a better way than doing something like:

```
val firstNames = ArrayList<String>()
accounts.forEach { firstNames.add(it.firstName) }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html):

```kotlin
val firstNames = accounts.map { it.firstName }
```